# How do I turn a django model method into a parameter?

Tags: python, django

I want to add the method has_access_token to a django model ... how can I turn it into a paramater?

meaning if I have the following method in the Person model:

```
def has_access_token(self):
    return True

person = Person.objects.get(user=user)
```

I want to be able to do:

```
if person.has_access_token:
```

without adding parenthesis: `()` like `person.has_access_token()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
@property
def has_access_token(self):
    return True
```

---

```
>>> class MyModel:
...     def has_access_token_1(self):
...         return True
...     @property
...     def has_access_token_2(self):
...         return True
... 
>>> 
>>> obj = MyModel()
>>> obj.has_access_token_1
<bound method MyModel.has_access_token_1 of <__main__.MyModel instance at 0x7f07ed881ea8>>
>>> obj.has_access_token_2
True
```